# Opening google chrome with batch file not able to use USB camera

Tags: windows-10, google-chrome, batch-file, camera

Opening any browser in windows 10 with batch file not able to use USB camera.

[Screenshot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4muZd.png)

Command used in batch file: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" https://www.onlinemictest.com/webcam-test/

Comment: Just need to confirm - 1. Do you have x86 version of google? Or you have changed its default location? 2. Does your camera work with any other app on your windows? 3. Does you camera work when you open it through the shortcut?

Comment: The word "It" in the 3rd question refers to google chrome

Comment: 1. Google chrome Version 92.0.4515 107 (official build) (64-bit). 2. No i haven't changed the default location. 3. Yes camera works when i open it by double clicking on shortcut. It also works when i launch google chrome with command line.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to replicate your problem, and I observed that there was a small problem in google chrome. When the site asks us for permissions to camera, and we click on allow on the popup, it still somehow blocks the camera. When you will click on the camera button on the search bar and select Continue Allowing, the issue will be resolved. I know that you have done it till here, but you also need to reload the site after that. Do this, and this will (probably) solve your problem.

PS: For clarity on this "bug", you can see it as bug between Chrome and its popup rather than a bug in the connection of Chrome and Camera

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Still facing same issue.

Comment: I tried with Firefox browser, same problem is there too.

Comment: Sorry, then. I don't know what is happening

Comment: No issues, I have found one solution that worked for me partially.

Answer (score 0):

Explorer can be used to open the chrome. But in that case URL needs to be entered manually. Launch chrome using below given command

`explorer /root, "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"`